# Parse platform include on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am creating a query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Cars");
```

And trying to include some staff:

```
query.include("vendor");
query.include("brand");
```

And after execute find included thinks aren't available in keys. How can I fix it?

Comment: use the parsedashboard . display table cars and verify 'type' on both  vendor, brand.  if they are type 'pointer' then they should be inlined by the query.include. if that does not help verify the versions of sdk in use. upgrade may b needed

Comment: @RobertRowntree i am using implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3' brand and vendors are pointer. When i am doing parseObject.get("brand") or parseObject.getParseObject("brand") it return null

Comment: Okey resolved don't know why but include doesn't work with  query.orderByAscending